# TikZ node coordinates (nodeName.number??)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, tikz-path

In the following example code:

```
...
\node (naveq) [naveqs] {Navigation equations};
\path (naveq.140)+(-\blockdist,0) node (gyros) [sensor] {Gyros};
...
```

what does `naveq.140` means?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It means 140 degrees from the east (right) side of the node `naveq`. The question is probably a duplicate, I'll see if I can find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is also possible to provide an angle instead of an anchor. This coordinate refers to a point of the node’s border where a ray shot from the center in the given angle hits the border.

This is from the pgfmanual on page 135.
So `(name.90)` would be equal to `(node.north)`, `(name.180)` is equal `(node.west)` and so on.